# Crop Image Issue when not showing Actual Image using C#

Tags: c#, image, jcrop

I am using `JCrop` to Crop `Image`. It is working fine if I show Actual Image to user. But, If I show Resize `Image` rather than Actual `Image` then I am getting `Co-ordinates` of Resize `Image`.
Then, How do I Crop `Image` based on it ? Here, I am passing `Image` path of Saved `Image`.
In short, If Saved `Image` size if for i.e. `715 * 350` then I am showing it in popup in Small Size based on CSS. So, I will get `Co-ordinates` of that Small Size `Image`. and I am applying those `Co-ordinates` on Main `Image`.

**My Code:**

```
using (System.Drawing.Image OriginalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Img))
            {
                using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height))
                {
                    bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);

                    using (System.Drawing.Graphics Graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    {
                        Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), X, Y, Width, Height, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);

                        ms.Close();
                        ms.Flush();
                        ms.Dispose();

                        return ms.GetBuffer();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

The code you show is made for resizing, not for cropping (In the `Graphic.DrawImage()` call, you don't care about the cropping coordinates, and just apply a destination Width/Height)

For cropping an image, you can just use the [`Bitmap.Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Just pass to it the cropping coordinates you extracted from `JCrop`. (`cropzone` in the following example)

```
public static async Task CropImage()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var sourceimg = new Uri(@"http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png");
    var destination = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logoCropped.png"));
    if (destination.Exists)
        destination.Delete();
    using (Stream sourceStream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(sourceimg))
    {
        using (Bitmap source = new Bitmap(sourceStream))
        {
            Rectangle cropzone = new Rectangle(0, 0, 256, 256);
            using (Bitmap croppedBitmap = source.Clone(cropzone, source.PixelFormat))
            {
                croppedBitmap.Save(destination.FullName, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some advices about your code :

- When just cropping, there's no resizing operation involved. So the `SmoothingMode`, `InterpolationMode`, `PixelOffsetMode` parameters are useless here.
- About the `MemoryStream`, you should better use it in a `using` statement. It avoids manual calls to `Close()` and `Dispose()`, and guaranty they're called whatever happens. And about the `Flush()` method, it [just does nothing](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/996367c59ff4f5de.html) on the `MemoryStream` class.

Answer (score 1):

Jcrop has `tureSize` property.

```
$.Jcrop('#image',{ trueSize: [715, 350] });
```

you should get the correct coordinates of the large image.

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html